# Break role inheritance via Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, role-assignment

I've been trying to switch between SharePoint REST API and Graph API and I can't find an equivalent of breakroleinheritance()

```
_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitename/Shared%20Documents/foldername')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(true)
```

doesn't seem to have a matching functionality in graph.

I tried listing all permissions via
`/drives/${driveId}/items/${someFolderId}/permissions`
and deleting them one by one, but it silently fails on one permission that's the main owners group and I can't delete it.

Tried looking for role management in Graph API but there's role management only for devices.

How do I break role inheritance through Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

I think MS Graph API has not exposed such an endpoint that could break role inheritance. You may have to continue using the old rest API.

BR

Comment: With the app authorization that looks like a phishing attack, I'd rather have a regular oauth to Graph API and less features :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody's looking for this, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) you can break inheritance by sending a sharing invite and setting `retainInheritedPermissions` to false

Unfortunately for the moment it forms a bad request. An issue has been logged [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/20888) - hopefully it will be fixed soon. For now, as @Baker_Kong says, the old API seems to be the only working way to do this